# System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException

Tags: c#, httpclient

I am trying to make a soap request:

```
 var _apiUrl = "https://www1.gsis.gr:443/wsaade/RgWsPublic2/RgWsPublic2";
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(
                    _apiUrl, new StringContent(
                      "myXML",
                        Encoding.UTF8,
                        "application/soap+xml"));
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                }
            }
```

When trying to make the request I am getting error in response

> " Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in
>   mscorlib.dll."

I have windows 7 64bit, and I am using the .net framework 4.7.2. If I will run the project in windows 10 or if I will downgrade my framework in 4.6.1 then it works fine. Why this is happening?
[image]

Comment: Your problem is on content-type `"text/xml; encoding='utf-8'"`  and `xml` serialization it should like this `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myXML);`

Comment: Than you  Md Farid Uddin Kiron, could you give give me an example?

Comment: Hi solution provided, hope that would help as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Its seems you are encountered that error because of wrong `xml serialization` it should be like `"text/xml; encoding='utf-8'"` and `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myXML)` instead of what you are trying.

You could try this way:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("RequestURL");
    byte[] bytes;
    bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("myXML");
    request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    request.Method = "POST";
    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();
    HttpWebResponse response;
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
        return responseStr;
    }
```

You could refer [Official Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netframework-4.8)

Hope that would help you.

Comment: I am still getting the same issue

Comment: How is your `xml` include that on your question as well.

Comment: Here is my xml https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XUemXD24OIojpVgolv_5EyuU-DlQZh3i/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You cannot pass `xml` that way, you have to convert in to C# class, then need to serialize it. finally have to pass that on above request [have a look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I am using XmlDocument load and then doc.OuterXml

Comment: I think that the problem is the content type. If i will downgrade to 4.6.1 framework it works only with application/soap+xml and not as text/xml

Comment: Agreed, problem on `content-type` either content has to serialized in a correct manner or version need to change, but given solution should work as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208903/discussion-between---and-md-farid-uddin-kiron).